# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at ClientDataManager.newChannel ClientDataManager.js:81:36

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

my node.js discord bot (discord.js based) suddenly shut down an hour ago and now produces an error on startup.

```
Bot started!

Found 3 commands, loading.

/var/www/bot/live/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/ClientDataManager.js:81
        guild.channels.set(channel.id, channel);
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at ClientDataManager.newChannel (/var/www/bot/live/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/ClientDataManager.js:81:36)
    at Guild.setup (/var/www/bot/live/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Guild.js:307:68)
    at GuildCreateHandler.handle (/var/www/bot/live/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/GuildCreate.js:12:15)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/var/www/bot/live/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/var/www/bot/live/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/var/www/bot/live/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/var/www/bot/live/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/var/www/bot/live/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

This is all I see. The script does the whole loading method and then just crashes.
And I'm not even using any channel info.

Any idea what this could be?

There have not been any updates. The server and bot wasn't touched for a month and worked flawless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem.

It seems that the issue is caused by the new "Stage channels" feature because deleting it on my serer solved the problem for me and my bot started fine. But I am a newbie so I am not sure if it's possible to fix it within the code.

Comment: Hey, Can you elaborate more? You removed the bot from your server? I have the bot on 150 servers or so, so I can't remove from all. Also, this only happens with the live bot, If I change apikey to dev, the code starts up just fine.

Comment: Ok, solved the issue. It really is "Stage channels" fault. I was running discord.js 11 wich is not compatible with the new feature. I upgraded to version 12 and the bot started up just fine. Thank you a lot